# How does python random.shuffle change the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

How does Python's random.shuffle() function change variables without the variable being set to it?

For example, if I did

```
def shuffle(array):
    shuffled = ... # Some code to shuffle array
    return shuffled
```

and I did

`array = shuffle(array)`

That would make sense, but how does the random library not require this step? There is no way to point to a variable in python so how does it set the variable

`shuffle(array)`

Without `array` explicitly being set to the returned value of `shuffle(array)`

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> `random.shuffle(x[, random])`
>   Shuffle the sequence x in place

They key here is **"in place"**, it means that it mutates the original array. So it do not need to return it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays passed in functions parameters are **references**, that's why you don't need to get a return value.

```
def change_arr(some_array):
    some_array[1] = "World"

arr = ['Hello', 'Hello']
print(arr)
change_arr(arr)
print(arr)
```

Output :

```
['Hello', 'Hello']
['Hello', 'World']
```